# Equivalent function of atoi Doesn't work

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to make a function equivalent of atoi. 1st i want to see that the transformations goes right but it doesn't. Can u please help me to figure out why it doesn't work?

```
int atoi2(char *string)
 {
  int i,numar,aux,p[10]={48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57};
  while(*string!='\0')
  {
   aux=(int)*string;

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
       if(p[i]==aux)
       {
           numar=numar*10+i;
       }
   }
  string++;
}
return numar;
}
```

Comment: `numar` is uninitialized.

Comment: And this, ladies and gentlemen, is why we declare variables only at the point *where we initialize them as well*. This ain't K&R anymore, you don't have to declare all variables at the top. Also, spaces are free, have some. They do *wonders* for legibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local variable must be initialized before its use, this is part of the policy of *don't pay for what you don't need* of C language.

In addition, there's no need to use an array in your case, since digits ASCII values are consecutive your code would be equivalent if you just subtract `48` from the ASCII value. So `*string - '0' == i`.

```
int numar = 0;
while (*string != '\0') {
  numar = numar*10 + (*string - '0');
  ++string;
}
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `*string - '0'` will cause different behavior than his original code if it contains non-numeric characters.

Comment: Yes, a check for `*string >= '0' && *string <= '9'` would be sane. But in any case relying on a specific encoding for characters, which is what the OP is doing, is not safe in any case so who cares in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize `numar`. If you don't explicitly set an automatic variable to a value, its value is undefined and the compiler can do whatever it likes. To fix this issue, change the third line to:

```
int i,numar=0,aux,p[10]={48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57};
```